# How to make jquery function work more than once

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me? I want to ask about the function on JQuery. When I gave JQuery function on my website, I want to provide these functions at 2 object. but somehow when I give the Jquery function to a second object, somehow function does not work. I provide these functions at two objects with the same id. so, anyone can help solve this problem?

Comment: It's probably worth you supplying the code your trying to get working so that we can get a bit more context.

Comment: Two objects with the same ID? I assume you're meaning elements, and if they have the same ID, it isn't valid.

Comment: Multiple elements can have the same class so you can apply a function to them like `$(".myclass").....` Use class instead of id.

Answer (score 2):

Two elements may not have the same ID. This is prohibited in HTML (and many other things). In fact, even the definition of ID prohibits it: ID = identification ⇒ unique.